# Why i cant open designer from App.xaml in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, mobile

I want develope a mobile application in Visual Studio 2022 Community.

But when i try to open designer from App.xaml its cant open.

I was tried:

- Repair, Uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio 2022
- When i click right i cant see open any designer there.
- Creating lot of new mobile apps project with Xamarin, Android.
- I check all of extensions and Visual Studio 2022 is up to date.
- I was watched lot of videos and research lot of websites. Like: Stackoverflow
- Tools - preferences - Xamarin Designer - Xamarin designer active is open already.

So how can i solve that problem anyone can help me about it ?

Comment: XF doesn't have a XAML designer.

Comment: which one i need select for this ? @Jason

Comment: you edit XAML with the XAML editor.  I'm not sure what you're asking.  As I already pointed out, there is not a visual designer for XF